# Count RDD Pairs As Dictionary Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have been working with a dataset that has been reduced to a following structure:

`10,47,110,296,318,356,364,377,454,527,539,590,593,597,648,858,1097,1197,1206,1214,1221,1265,1291,1721,1961,2571,2628,2706,2716,3147,3578,3717,3793,4306,4993,5952,6539,7153,7438`

Where each row of the RDD has the above structure.

I am attempting to count each pair within the row and insert the value to a dictionary.  A sample output for this dictionary would be:
`(10,47): 1, (10, 110):1, (10,296):1` etc.

I was able to get a basic implementation working but it was taking ten minutes longer on larger datasets vs. a simpler non dictionary approach in pyspark (I am practicing pairs and stripes mapreduce algorithms)

Previously, I was calling my own reduce function that would iterate through all the combination of pairs and then emit the counts for that. Is there a better way to be doing this?

The end goal is to count each row of an RDD and have a dictionary for `(val1,val2): count`

With the above data example as an rdd called `dataRDD` I have been performing the following

`pairCount = dataRDD.map(combinePairs)`

Where combinePairs is defined as

```
goodDict =  defaultdict(int)
def combinePairs(data):
data = data.split(',')
for v in itertools.combinations(data,2):
    first = v[0]
    second = v[1]

    pair = (first,second)

    goodDict[pair] = goodDict[pair]+1
return goodDict
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: In the end, you want to combine all dictionaries into one final dictionary for a rdd or do you rdd of dictionaries as separate record?

Comment: @mayankagrawal end goal is to have a dictionary with pairs and counts

Comment: then you can probably use aggregateByKey here to get one final dictionary